# How to return the cheapest price?

Tags: sql, oracle, top-n

I have a table named `sales` and it has 2 columns: `Sales_Id` and `Price`. I need to retrieve the cheapest price from the table. The cheapest price is 100. However, it shows only for one `Sales_ID` whereas I want it to return all 3 entries with the cheapest price.

```
Create table sales
(
   Sales_Id int Primary Key,
   Price number(4)
);
insert into sales values( 1,100);
insert into sales values( 2,400);
insert into sales values( 3,100);
insert into sales values( 4,100);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select sales_id
from sales
where price = (select min(price) from sales)
```

Answer (score 2):

One method uses `rank()`/`dense_rank()`:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*, rank() over (order by price) as seqnum
      from sales s
     ) s
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from sales
order by price
fetch first row with ties;
```

(Requires Oracle 12.1 or later.)